# Way to keep null values in the output? (Oracle)

Tags: oracle

So I'm working with this data base and I get the following output

```
L1  L2  L3
5   5   5
5   8   5
5   5   
5   8   5
5   8   5
```

I want to make sure that only data with 5 is seen even if there is data with an empty "null" space.

using

```
where 5 = all(l1,l2,l3)
```

almost works but it gets rid of the ones with empty spaces. Is there a way to keep the null spaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe

```
where 5 = all (nvl(l1, 5),
               nvl(l2, 5),
               nvl(l3, 5)
              )
```

Comment: Do, or do not - there is no "maybe".